# What exactly happens when we are trying to ping domain and what difference to ping to wakodikarkanchan.com and www.wakodikarkanchan.com

Tags: networking, dns, ip, ping

What exactly happens when we are trying to ping domain and what difference to ping to wakodikarkanchan.com and www.wakodikarkanchan.com

when I try to ping www.google.com its ping to www.google.com and when ping to my website i.e www.wakodikarkanchan.com its ping to wakodikarkanchan.com, what difference in both stages.

[this is how ping to both domains and its take more time to ping with my site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Jk5m.jpg)

and same, I cant browse my website with IP address how do I activate it ?

Answer (score 0):

It pings the IP, not the domain. The domain is resolved to the IP and then the domain is not used. All packages are sent to IP address.

`www.google.com` has an `A record` pointed to an IP. Ping resolves it to that IP and pings the IP.
`www.wakodikarkanchan.com` has a `CNAME record`, pointed to `wakodikarkanchan.com`, which has an `A record` pointed to the IP address. So Ping resolves it to the domain name and then to the IP, that is why you see this change.

As for the screenshot - as I said ping pings the IP and the time depends on everything between you and that IP. If you have a good connectivity with `Google`, than with your web host (for instance if the Google's server you are pinging is in your country and your web host is at the other end of the world) then it is normal to see such time differences.